# text shows strangely in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, text, fonts, terminal

what happened to my text ?
I tried to update locale .. it is not the case.

number 2 and "n" are showing strange...

any ideas?

==>>

[image]

Comment: Looks like your fontmap is messed up.  What happens when you change the font?

Comment: yes, I changed fonts properties text scaling factor to 1.05  or hinting to medium etc ..... it is normal again.... still don't know what the problem was exactly.. .. but working.. thanks..

Comment: Sometimes the fontmap can just get messed up in memory.  So, each time that character comes up, it's already hosed.  Even if your physical font map is fine, this can happen.  A simple restart of the service will fix that.